# no me separa la cadena con espacios pero si con caracteres

Tags: java, array, string, split

Hola llevo ya un par de dias con la misma duda y nada de lo que encuentro por internet funciona a pesar de que todo el mundo escribe los mismo y dice lo mismo y es que cuando trato de usar split() para que me devuelva un array de string pasandole como parametro un spacio entre comillas solo me devuelve el primer valor antes del primer el espacio pero el resto ni lo almacena es como si no existiera nada mas alla del primer espacio y solo fuera una palabra

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class arrays {
    public static Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Introduce lineas");
        String palabras=teclado.next();
        String[] palabra=palabras.split(" ");
        for (String p: palabra) {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que lo que planteas funcione correctamente en lugar de usar `next()`, debes de usar `nextLine();`

```
    System.out.println("Introduce líneas");
    String palabras=teclado.nextLine();
    String[] palabra=palabras.split(" ");
    for (String p: palabra) {
        System.out.println(p);
    }
```

Captura del código funcionando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No funciona correctamente con `next()` ya que este lee solo hasta que encuentra un espacio, mientras que `nextLine()` como bien menciona su nombre, lee la línea completa hasta el salto de línea.

**Más información :** [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre next() y nextLine() en Java?](https://respuestasit.wordpress.com/2015/06/13/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-next-y-nextline-en-java/)

Comment: Gracias a dios si es que la solucion era una tonteria enorme, muchas gracias ^^

Comment: Siempre me pasan tonterías similares hahaha :) me alegro de ayudar, si es que esta respuesta ha solucionado tu problema no olvides de marcarla como aceptada, al lado izquierdo de la misma en el símbolo check (✓) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Para separar una cadena por espacios y crear un array, te sugiero usar :

```
.split("\\s+");
```

y muy importante usar `nextLine();` en lugar de `next();`, ya que `next()` únicamente obtendría la cadena hasta encontrar un espacio, por lo tanto no se guardaría todo el texto.

de esta forma:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class arrays {
    public static Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Introduce lineas");
        String palabras=teclado.nextLine();
        String[] palabra=palabras.split("\\s+");
        for (String p: palabra) {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }
}
```

ejemplo:

```
Introduce lineas
Hola soy Borja Lorenzo    
Hola
soy
Borja
Lorenzo
```